# Compactness of $\mathbb{R}$ with the trivial and the discrete topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology, is $\mathbb{R}$ compact?

Answer :no, it doesn't exist an open  finite cover

---

Let $\mathbb{R}$ with the  trivial topology, is $\mathbb{R}$ compact?

Answer :no, there is only one possible open cover $\mathbb{R}$ itself, and it can't be finite

Is my answers correct?

Comment: There are only two sets in the trivial topology, so any open cover is finite.

Comment: It seems like you misunderstand the definition of compactness. To show a space is compact, you must start with an arbitrary open cover and prove it has a finite subcover. To show a space is *not* compact you must exhibit a specific open cover and prove that it has no finite subcover.

Comment: Thanks everyone, now I get it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a finite open cover of $\mathbb R$ with the discrete topology, namely the cover whose only member is $\mathbb R$ itself. But **some** open covers, in particular $\{ \{x\} : x\in\mathbb R \},$ have no finite subcover, so this space is not compact.

You are right that there is only one open cover of $\mathbb R$ with the trivial topolgy, namely the open cover whose only member is $\mathbb R$ itself. But it is finite, since it contains only one member, namely $\mathbb R$ itself.

Answer (score 2):

But $\mathbb R$ with the discrete topology does have a finite cover: $\{\mathbb R\}$ is a finite cover.

And in $\mathbb R$ with the trivial topology, $\{\mathbb R\}$ itself is also a finite cover.

You might wish to ponder the fact that a *cover* of a set $X$ is a set $\{C_i\}$ of subsets $C_i \subset X$. When talking about whether a cover is finite or infinite, what matters is not whether the subsets $C_i$ themselves contain finitely many or infinitely many elements. What matters is whether the set $\{C_i\}$ contains finitely many or infinitely many elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are misreading the definition of compact. You have to know whether every cover by open sets has a finite subcover.

That does not mean the open sets in the cover have only finitely many elements, it means you need only finitely many of the open sets.

To show a space is not compact you can look for some cover by infinitely many open sets for which no finite subset covers. To show a space is compact you must reason about all possible open covers.